# adding babel-plugin-transform-remove-console in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native 0.61.*` and created project with `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` but could not find `.babelrc` file as mentioned in this [official doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements) of adding `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console`.

How would i include the `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console`? Just create the a new `.babelrc` file and it will work magically? Or do i edit in `.babelrc` file?

Answer (score 0):

the babel config in the latest react native build is `babel.config.js` i believe. This is where you would add that plugin.